# Ordering of bands in ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, arccatalog, multi-band, sorting

I have a multi-band GeoTIFF with >10 bands, for example 11. I would have expected these to be shown in an ordered numerical sequence from 1 to 11. However, ArcCatalog 10.3.1 wants to show the string sorted list of bands:

[image: Default]

**How can I fix this to make ArcCatalog sort bands by their band number?**

---

One manual fix within ArcCatalog is to rename (e.g.) `Band_1` to `Band_01` by clicking each of these, repeating this until `Band_09`. But that's a lot of clicking and manual effort! And it adds a `.aux.xml` sidecar file (yuk!)

My other attempt to fix this is to use GDAL to set each band's `Description` metadata to `Band_01`, `Band_02`, ..., `Band_11`, which looks like this (via `gdalinfo`):

```
Band 1 Block=365x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = Band_01
Band 2 Block=365x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Band_02
...
Band 11 Block=365x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Band_11
```

ArcCatalog is now happy to sort every band, except for `Band_1`.

[image: Attempt]

Furthermore, ArcCatalog allows me to rename any band except for `Band_1`, so I can't change this name or sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be when the band names are stored in GDAL metadata in the GeoTIFF rather than in the sidecar aux.xml.  I don't know whether this is related to ArcGIS itself, or the really old (1.8 esri branch) version of GDAL that ArcGIS 10.3.1 ships with.  I don't have a GDAL 1.8 intallation to test with

Workaround - force sidecar aux.xml PAM metadata file by creating your GeoTIFFs with the `PROFILE=GeoTIFF` [creation option](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html), not the default (which is `PROFILE=GDALGeoTIFF`), then set band names.

E.g

```
...
dst_ds = driver.Create( dst_filename, ncols, nrows, nbands, gdal_datatype, ['PROFILE=GEOTIFF'] )
...
for band in range(nbands):
    rb.SetDescription('B%s' % str(band+1).zfill(2))
```

```
gdalinfo c:\temp\test_f64.tif

    ...
Band 1 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray      
  Description = B01                                    
Band 2 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined 
  Description = B02                                    
Band 3 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined 
  Description = B03                                    
Band 4 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined 
  Description = B04                                    
Band 5 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined 
  Description = B05                                    
Band 6 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined 
  Description = B06                                    
Band 7 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined 
  Description = B07                                    
Band 8 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined 
  Description = B08                                    
Band 9 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined 
  Description = B09                                    
Band 10 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B10                                    
Band 11 Block=512x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = B11
```

[image]

Comment: It seems this is just a quirk with ArcCatalog. The RGB composite is always correct (1, 2, 3), and ArcMap correctly shows the proper sorted list of bands in the Layer Properties dialog. Esri should fix ArcCatalog to be consistent with their other components. Nevertheless, this sidecar file fixes ArcCatalog's display, thanks!